OpenRewrite is not visiting files from src/integration-tests/java directory
I am using org.openrewrite.java.RemoveUnusedImports recipe to remove unused imports so it does not fails on SonarQube (I have a pipeline configured to run the tests before SonarQube). However, when I forget to remove an unused import, the recipe (which runs at the beginning of the pipeline) does not detect it.
Anyone knows how to modify the project scope?
As I can see from the documentation, the directories which analyze by default are:

src/main/java - Recipe implementations

src/test/java - Recipe tests


I am expecting the recipe to be applied to all the files under src/**: main, tests and integration-tests.

Could you share how you've configured Maven to use that additional src/integration-tests/java directory? That might help us troubleshoot, as we rely on Maven to tell us about which source sets are in use.

Hi @Tim, thanks for the quick reply. I run the following command inside the pipeline stage:
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:RELEASE:run $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=$REWRITE_DEPENDENCIES -Drewrite.activeRecipes=$REWRITE_RECIPES -Drewrite.exclusions=${REWRITE_EXCLUSIONS} -Drewrite.runPerSubmodule=false (all environment variables are predefined before run the stage)

Why is the strange directory used? Follow the conventions... production code src/main/java unit- and integration tests in src/test/java (separation via naming convention: unit test *Test.java and integration tests *IT.java )...

Hi @khmarbaise, you are right. However, moving all ITs to the test folder is hard now. I would like to know if it is possible to analyze files allocated in other folders rather than conventional src/main and src/test

Could you share how in your pom.xml you've configured the additional source set?

Right now the rewrite-maven-plugin only parses the main & test source sets, as seen here: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/blob/f1d652fa7947ad178c1b3f5fdef9f81846362a4e/src/main/java/org/openrewrite/maven/MavenMojoProjectParser.java#L182-L183

Hi @Tim, how can I configure additional source set in the pom file?

I wouldn't immediately know, and any new source set would not automatically be picked up by our plugin yet, given the link to the source shown above. I'll side with Karl Heinz here that it would be best to follow the Maven conventions (as always) in your test naming scheme if at all possible. Understandably that might be a bit of a change there, but it would make things more predictable.

Related github issue - https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/issues/755
